# Make Alt attribute to have Super Script

Tags: javascript, html

I am not able to figure this out for a while now.

I want to use super script in Alt attribute of an image. The code that I have made works fine when I use it with

```
document.write
innerHTML
```

because I understand that the HTML parser when reads the script reads the `<sup></sup>` tags and makes the text between it as superscript. But how to make the **Alt** attribute or rather an `<input>` tag have a superscript value.

I want something like this:

```
<input type="text" value="Hi, this is my 1<sup>st</sup> award">
```

to output on the screen as an input box with pre-filled text

[image]

I have made the following code, but cannot figure it out to put it in place:

```
<body>
<img src="test.jpg" height="400px" width="500px" alt=''>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var title = "Test String having 1st";
   var one = "st";
   one='1'+one.sup();
   title = title.replace(/1st/g, one);
   document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].setAttribute('alt',title);
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: You cannot nest elements in attributes. You can, however, use UNICODE code points that map to superscript letters, e.g. `alt="Hi, this is my 1&#x2e2;&#x1d57; award"`.

Comment: Or you can handle "onerror" event to catch if image isn't loaded: `<img src="missing" onerror="this.outerHTML = '<span>Hi, this is my 1<sup>st</sup> award</span>'"/>`

Comment: I tried this but not working var title = "Test String having 1&sups;&sup2; award";

Comment: and that what Frederic you wrote is also not working..

Comment: @Yuriry, that is not required, thanks for the advice though..I have to get it done that way

Comment: @I_AM_NOT_A_CODER, really? It works for me in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLo0j8n8/). Maybe a font issue on your end, although I doubt it.

Comment: I added the meta for charset <meta charset="UTF-8"> and wrote this var title = "Test String having 1&#x2e2;&#x1d57; award"; and also the DOCTYPE is defined for HTML5

Comment: Well, yeah, HTML entities are not suitable for JavaScript strings, you would have to use the UNICODE code points directly. However, your question was about HTML attributes, not JavaScript strings.

Answer (score -1):

For easier solution you can use an editor and remove the toolbar and set the html content of it, here is an example editor https://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/ , you can easily turn off the toolbar and then add your desired html to it.

For alt you can use the on error attribute and call a custom attribute on it. Let me know if you need any further elaboration.

Comment: Muaaz, that is actually not desired. I want to write a string that is interpreted that way directly!

Comment: You will need to create an html container and display the value there and then you can display it no other way here you can read the https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4 and the above solution makes the other stuff for you. Rest is upto you.